# Referencing delayed_job job id from within the job task

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I've got a delayed_job task that spits out a file. I'd like to be able to prefix the file with the ID of the job that created it, to easily reference it later on.

```
# Create a file that has the job id in the name...
job_id = thing.delay.create_file
# Now we'll use the job_id to search for the file...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please include the code in the create_file task.

Comment: DJ deletes entries when it is done with them so how is the job ID any use to you?

Comment: @muistooshort - failed jobs don't get deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it from here...

```
class WriteFileJob
  attr_accessor :dj_id, :file_name

  def initialize(file_name)
    @file_name = file_name
  end

  def perform
    # do something with @dj_id; don't worry, we'll set it below
  end
end
```

Now when you enqueue the job, you should get a job back:

```
j = Delayed::Job.enqueue(WriteFileJob.new("foo.txt"))
```

Next, you load the object that you enqueued, and updated it with the id you just got back:

```
object_to_update = YAML.load(j.handler)
object_to_update.dj_id = j.id
# update the handler
j.handler = object_to_update.to_yaml
j.save
```

Comment: @Yarin :-) In case you are worried about the job being executed too early (before @dj_id gets assigned), you could throw an exception `if @dj_id.nil?` so the job would run again at a later time (or you could specify run_at in the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

delayed_job uses a table to queue jobs and that table can be found in the [Gem's migration file](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/blob/master/generators/delayed_job_migration/templates/migration.rb).  That table will have a default id column which you can query for:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare("Select id FROM delayed_job where handler=?","YAML Encoded string representing the object doing work")
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work, though I'm hoping for something that doesn't involve re-querying the db.